# Shopware 6: Add product slider to customized shop page

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have created a custom shop page layout and added a product slider.
But I don't see anything on the storefront. Is there some special configuration that has to be set?

Answer (score 1):

You can double check the page with new custom layout that has product slider

Make sure that page is using right layout
[image]

Check product slider exists
[image]

Comment: if your shop has multiple languages, check the languge when you editing